# Regular Expression Error while matching a character

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex which check a character if it is A-z 0-9 space ' & _ [ ] ^ `.

```
I tried [a-zA-Z0-9 '&_[]^`]
```

It is having error.
Please help.

Comment: Escape the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the brackets within character class :

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 '&_\[\]^`]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the closing bracket to let it know where actually the character set ends.

You can also escape `[`.. but it is redundant here:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 '&_[\]^`]
```